# Python importing package gpiosimulator fails

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to debug a `Raspberry Pi` program on Windows. 
On `Windows 7` with `IDLE 3.6.2` I imported package `GPIOSimulator` without error. I import pip and execute `sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()])`

and get the following so it seems that `gpiosimulator` was installed.

```
['flake8==3.4.1', 'gpiosimulator==0.1', 'gpiozero==1.4.0', 'keyboard==0.11.0', 'mccabe==0.6.1', 'pigpio==1.35', 'pip==9.0.1', 'pycodestyle==2.3.1', 'pyflakes==1.5.0', 'setuptools==28.8.0']
```

However when I import `gpiosimulator` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpiosimulator'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to take a look at your previous question on here. Make sure you're installing the module to the correct pip library

Answer (score 1):

The module is not imported as `gpiosimulator`

You can import the modules with

```
import RPiSim, RPiSim.GPIO
```

[See the API documentation for more information](https://pypkg.com/pypi/gpiosimulator/api/)